# Boost library issues

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile a simple c++ program using g++ which contains boost includes but i am getting the following error. I installed it from the tar file found in the boost site. I get the following error only with the asio library.

```
$ g++ -std=c++03 -Wall -pedantic -g -O2 tcp.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_thread -lboost_asio
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_asio
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: cannot find -lboost_asio is self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Boost Asio is header only.

Drop `-lboost_asio`

Comment: it compiles when i drop it but i get the following error while running the pgm..
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm not sure Asio counts as "header-only" if it has dependencies on components that do require compilation.

Comment: i am trying to compile a example program from boost asio page

Answer (score 0):

ASIO doesn't have a library built for it, so indicating `-lboost_asio` as an option doesn't really make sense.

However, ASIO does have a dependency on boost.system, which does require a library be built for it.

Make sure you've properly built the boost library in the first place (correct optimization flags, correct Runtime-Library linking, correct architecture, and so on), and that the generated library files (the .so files, in your case) are accessible to the executable.